# Authorizing Azure Function App Http endpoint from Data Factory

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-functions, azure-data-factory, azure-managed-identity

We are currently developing an ETL solution in Azure Data Factory that requires calling out to an Azure Function App HTTP trigger. Our Data Factory instance has a Managed Identity configured and I was wondering how I can secure the Azure Function App to only allow access from the Data Factroy Managed Identity?

I have previously used Azure Function Apps System Assigned Managed Identities to access other resources (Key Vault) so I understand the basic concepts, but I am struggling to understand if using System Assigned Managed Identities as a authorization and authentication mechanism on Azure Function Apps is possible.

Comment: Hi, any update this issue?

Comment: Very valid question.  I have same question for a while. If we enable managed identity in DataFactory and Function app then can't they talk to each other through AD automatically. Do we have to explicitly enable `Authentication/Authorization` on function app and create another AD Application ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, please follow the steps below.

1.Navigate to your function app in the portal -> `Authentication / Authorization` -> configure it with Azure AD auth, follow this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad#-configure-with-express-settings). **Note:** In `Express`, we select `Create New AD App`, it will reduce unnecessary trouble.

After configuration, it will be like below.

[image]

2.After a while, navigate to `Azure Active Directory` in the portal -> `App registrations` -> search for your function app name with the filter `All applications` -> click it -> `App roles | Preview` -> `Create app role` -> create the role like below -> `Apply`.

[image]

Navigate to `Overview` -> click `Managed application in local directory`.

[image]

In the `Properties` -> set `User assignment required?` to `Yes`.

[image]

3.Use the powershell below to give the app role to your MSI(managed identity), replace the `<datafactory-name>` and `<functionapp-name>`.

Make sure you have installed the [`AzureAD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/install-adv2?view=azureadps-2.0#installing-the-azure-ad-module) powershell module and have enough permission to assign the app role.

```
Connect-AzureAD
$MSI = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "displayName eq '<datafactory-name>'"
$funapp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "displayName eq '<functionapp-name>'"
$PermissionName = "Function.Test"
$approle = $funapp.AppRoles | Where-Object {$_.Value -eq $PermissionName}
New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $MSI.ObjectId -PrincipalId $MSI.ObjectId -ResourceId $funapp.ObjectId -Id $approle.Id
```

[image]

4.Navigate to the httptrigger in your function app, set the `Authorization level` to `Anonymous`, because we have configured AAD auth.

[image]

5.Then in your ADF, create a web activity to test, use the settings like below.

```
URL - https://<functionapp-name>.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTrigger1

Resource - https://<functionapp-name>.azurewebsites.net
```

[image]

Run it, it will work fine.

[image]

In this solution, we secure the function with the app role, if you don't give the role to your MSI i.e. step 3, the MSI will not be able to access the function, in another word, if you just give the role only to your MSI, only your MSI will be able to access the function.

Comment: To make this work, I had to replace "Resource" in step 5 with the application ID of the App registration that is associated with the function app.