# Calling Azure Function from ADF using MSI

Tags: azure, function, azure-data-factory, azure-function-app, azure-managed-identity

I am trying to call a Function app from ADF using MSI.
I have enabled managed identity for ADF as well as have enabled AAD authentication/authorization for Function app.

[image]

Now when I make a web call from ADF (with the underlying specification)

[image]

I get the following error.

[image]

I even added ADF as contributor to Function App.
I must be missing something, but not sure what exactly

Comment: AAD on the Function might be evaluating the MSI of ADF. To test function within the FunctionApp, browse to the `Function Keys` if there none add new. Else copy the key and build the url in the ADF as `https://<funtionapp>.azurewebsites.net/api/<function>?code=<code>`

Comment: Thank you for your input @koushik. That indeed might work, but the intention is to enable a secured integration, without having to use/expose keys. Hence, looking for something that will enable to authenticate through MSI.

Comment: @JosephXu yes they are! clearly I am missing something. can you please share the steps...that will be very helpful. I can then try it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, please make sure you selected the [`Create New AD App`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad#-configure-with-express-settings) option when you configure the function app with Azure AD auth, then azure will do all the configurations for you automatically, this will reduce unnecessary trouble. Also remember to set `Authorization level` of your function to `Anonymous`, because we configured the function app with Azure AD auth.

In your case, the error was caused by the wrong `Resource`, it should be the `Application ID URI` of the AD App corresponded to the function app, i.e. `https://<functionapp-name>.azurewebsites.net`(this is configured by azure automatically when you select `Create New AD App` as mentioned above).

**Besides**, you should note, if you just do the steps above, all the service principals(MSI is essentially a service principal)/users in your AAD tenant can access the function app, if you just want your MSI to access the function app, then you need to leverage the [Azure AD App role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps), I have posted the details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65178711/authorising-azure-function-app-http-endpoint-from-data-factory/65192318#65192318), if you don't mind this, just ignore the step 2 and step 3, it will also work.

Comment: thank you for helping out on this. It indeed solved the issue. The error was the wrong Resource. After replacing it with `https://<functionapp-name>.azurewebsites.net` it worked perfectly!