# Redirect to login with AAD in Azure App Service Authentication vs Authentication (Classic)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-authentication

I'm trying to set up a system where an Azure DataFactory can call an Azure function through its managed identity. Good example here: [Authorising Azure Function App Http endpoint from Data Factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65178711/authorising-azure-function-app-http-endpoint-from-data-factory/65192318#65192318)

However, this was using the old(er) Authentication/Authorization tool for Azure functions, which has now been renamed Authentication (Classic). Setting the system up through this is fine, I can make the call and get a response, but upgrading to Authorization causes this to break. It seems like the key thing missing is the option of "Action to take when the request is not authenticated", which I cannot seem to set with the new Authorization tool but should be set to "Login with Azure AD"

In summary, how do I set this setting with the new Authorization tool so that a MSI can make a cool to the function and authenticate with AAD.

Image with classic

[image]

Image with new Authorization (no visible way to redirect to AAD)

[image]

In summary, how do I set this setting with the new Authorization tool so that a MSI can make a cool to the function and authenticate with AAD.

Comment: Here are possibly two methods of authentications: Delegated(login flow) and Application(Backend Services flow). For your scenario Client Credentials(Backend Services) is the best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work with the new `Authentication`, follow the steps below.

1.Edit the `Authentication settings` in the portal or set it when creating the app  as below.

[image]

2.Edit the `Identity provider`, make sure the `Issuer URL` is `https://sts.windows.net/<tenant-id>`(**without `/v2.0`**) and `Allowed token audiences` include the `App ID URI`.

[image]

[image]

For the `App ID URI`, you could check it in your AD App of the function app -> `Expose an API`, if you use the old `Authentication` before, maybe it is your function app URL, it does matter, just make sure `Allowed token audiences` include it.

[image]

3.Then in the datafactory web activity, also make sure the resource is the `App ID URI`.

[image]

Then it will work fine.

[image]

**Update:**

You could refer to my configuration.

Function app:

[image]

[image]

AD App:

[image]

[image]

AD App manifest:

```
{
    "id": "xxxxxx",
    "acceptMappedClaims": null,
    "accessTokenAcceptedVersion": null,
    "addIns": [],
    "allowPublicClient": null,
    "appId": "xxxxx",
    "appRoles": [],
    "oauth2AllowUrlPathMatching": false,
    "createdDateTime": "2021-06-08T01:51:06Z",
    "disabledByMicrosoftStatus": null,
    "groupMembershipClaims": null,
    "identifierUris": [
        "api://xxxxx"
    ],
    "informationalUrls": {
        "termsOfService": null,
        "support": null,
        "privacy": null,
        "marketing": null
    },
    "keyCredentials": [],
    "knownClientApplications": [],
    "logoUrl": null,
    "logoutUrl": null,
    "name": "joyfuna2",
    "oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow": true,
    "oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": false,
    "oauth2Permissions": [
        {
            "adminConsentDescription": "Allow the application to access joyfuna2 on behalf of the signed-in user.",
            "adminConsentDisplayName": "Access joyfuna2",
            "id": "1704f162-421d-4733-855f-5d93c0c55689",
            "isEnabled": true,
            "lang": null,
            "origin": "Application",
            "type": "User",
            "userConsentDescription": "Allow the application to access joyfuna2 on your behalf.",
            "userConsentDisplayName": "Access joyfuna2",
            "value": "user_impersonation"
        }
    ],
    "oauth2RequirePostResponse": false,
    "optionalClaims": null,
    "orgRestrictions": [],
    "parentalControlSettings": {
        "countriesBlockedForMinors": [],
        "legalAgeGroupRule": "Allow"
    },
    "passwordCredentials": [
        {
            "customKeyIdentifier": null,
            "endDate": "2031-06-08T01:51:05.573Z",
            "keyId": "c6d4434f-7aaf-4c4c-9428-a38cbf8200bb",
            "startDate": "2021-06-08T01:51:05.573Z",
            "value": null,
            "createdOn": "2021-06-08T01:51:07.3876164Z",
            "hint": "UT_",
            "displayName": "Generated by App Service"
        }
    ],
    "preAuthorizedApplications": [],
    "publisherDomain": "xxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com",
    "replyUrlsWithType": [
        {
            "url": "https://joyfuna2.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback",
            "type": "Web"
        }
    ],
    "requiredResourceAccess": [
        {
            "resourceAppId": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
            "resourceAccess": [
                {
                    "id": "e1fe6dd8-ba31-4d61-89e7-88639da4683d",
                    "type": "Scope"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "samlMetadataUrl": null,
    "signInUrl": "https://joyfuna2.azurewebsites.net",
    "signInAudience": "AzureADMyOrg",
    "tags": [],
    "tokenEncryptionKeyId": null
}
```

Datafactory web activity:

[image]

Comment: Hi Joy, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, this still didn't work and I'm getting an error in ADF along the lines of 'Audience validation failed, audiences did not match'. I've set the parameters to what you've suggested, including removing v2.0 in the Issuer URL. Are there any other settings that might be causing this?

Comment: @Aegir Did you use anything else to secure your function e.g. APIM ?

Comment: no it's just a basic Python function using the HttpTrigger template provided by Azure. Calling through browser allows me to get the response. 
Identity provider settings: ID provider: MS. Supported Account Types: Current Tenant-single tenant
Issuer URL: https://sts.windows.net/<tenant_ID>
Allowed token audience: api://<app_id>

Comment: Are there any additional RBAC roles the ADF identity needs to have on the RG? Seems unlikely but willing to try anything at this point

Comment: @Aegir It does not need any RBAC roles, could you delete the AD App and create a new one to configure again? There may be some other settings configured but I don't pay attention to.

Comment: @Aegir Double-check the three places use the same value i.e. App ID URI, `Expose an API`, `Allowed token audience`, `Resource`.

Comment: Okay, brand new app service appears to work. Perhaps it was an issue during the upgrade from classic to new or something else I'd accidentally tweaked. Thanks very much for your time and help with this, I appreciate it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233492/discussion-between-aegir-and-joy-wang).

Comment: @Aegir See my update, also note, to do a quick test, I didn't use the `App role` as I mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65178711/authorising-azure-function-app-http-endpoint-from-data-factory/65192318#65192318).

Comment: After working through this for a long time, the issue was that I had “api://ID” in the ADF Resource field. Removing the “api://“ fixed this issue.